# Display problem - newly built desktop PC

Tags: display-resolution

Just finished building a new desktop PC with following configuration:

> RAM  Corsair Vengeance RGB PRO CMW32GX4M2C3200C16 DDR4 3200MHz 32GB
> Kit (16GB*2)
>
> CPU  AMD Ryzen 5 3400G YD3400CCPU BOX w/Cooler
>
> Motherboard  ASUS PRIME X570-P/CSM X570,AM4 Socket,USB3.2,PCIe 4.0 M.2
> ATX M/B
>
> HDD  Samsung 2TB 860 EVO Series MZ-76E2T0BW 2.5" SATA3 6Gb/s
> SSD

I'm still running an old 25" DELL 3K display (Resolution 2560x1440) and now shopping a >30" 4K display.

I'm now test-building Ubuntu 16.04 desktop on an 180G SSD Drive.  The PC is now up running but it is still working on a [Build-in Display], resolution [1024x768(4:3)].  No other selection is available?

Please advise how to fix the problem.  I need a driver from AMD or from ASUS?

Please advise.  Thanks in advance.

Regards
satimis

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. But I will recommend to upgrade latest LTS 18.04, or maybe even the newly released 19.10, for up to date hardware support.

Comment: graphics driver questions are very hardware + driver specific ... so to gain traction I suggest you update your question to include output from running the various commands listed at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111123

Comment: @user108763 are you saying the best resolution you can get is 1024x768 after installing Ubuntu 16.04 ? Please clarify your question by clicking [edit] above.